# test performance - rollback vs restoring point

Tags: database, oracle

I'd like to performe a preformance test on my database. 
Is it okay to simply measure time of each transaction and after that perform rollback (will database restore to exactly the same state as if transaction wouldn't be executed)?
Or should I create a restore point and after each transaction use it?
When it comes to this second approach I followed this tutorial:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-nov/o66recovery-098482.html
Unfortunetely after restoring database I couldn't connect to it again. The error I received was ORA-01033. I waited for about 15 minutes but still I couldn't log back.

tl;dr
Can I use rollback after each executed transaction to return database to a previous state instead of using restore points?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`rollback` is an action which you can perform on a single transaction-scope - if you have a non-commited transaction, it would rollback to the state of the last `commit` / `rollback`.

On the other hand, **restore point** operates on a whole another level - on a schema / whole database level. It lets you set a restore point in a specific point in time (a specific `SCN`, for instance) and then basically you can snap back to this point. Any change to data, since the restore point "moment" , will be lost.

It's a great tool for testing a database upgrade for instance - you can set a restore point in a "stable" point in time and then do as many tests as you want, without the need to manually restore all the changes that have been made. You can just go back to the "safe" restore point at any time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I know what rollback and restore point does. The question was - if I use rollback on only one executed transaction is it equivalent to restoring database?

Comment: It is not the same - when you perform a rollback, you're using Rollback Segments and physically interact with the database SGA and blocks (high watermarks are effected, created Extents won't be destroyed, buffer cache is being "polluted" by those blocks etc.). As I understand - restore point is a far "cleaner" option, but obviously requires some extra work and time.